# How can I convert that json string to my class

Tags: gson

I have a json string that has a data like this:

```
description: { "en" : "english desc", "es": "spanish description" }
```

This field is in my Item class, but it is a string:

```
class Item

private String description;
```

I am using GSON to parse this Json. I am getting error because data in Json string is not a string. It's a JSON object.

I should give a parameter of default language(en for example) and it should be parsed like:

```
description =  "english desc"
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Description should be a composite object which contains en and es string fields as per your input string.
refer e.g.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Demo1 {

    class Item {

        Description description;

        public Description getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(Description description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Item [" + description + "]";
        }

        class Description {
            String en;
            String es;

            public String getEn() {
                return en;
            }

            public void setEn(String en) {
                this.en = en;
            }

            public String getEs() {
                return es;
            }

            public void setEs(String es) {
                this.es = es;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return "Description [en=" + en + ", es=" + es + "]";
            }

        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        String json = "{ description: { \"en\" : \"english desc\", \"es\": \"spanish description\" } }";

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Item i = gson.fromJson(json, Item.class);
        System.out.println("item:" + i);
    }
}
```